# jQuery AJAX request won't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax login on my site and for some strange reason, it won't work in internet explorer yet it works in Webkit, latest version of FireFox, and Opera. So I don't think it is my code but is there a known problem with ajax requests for IE? Thanks!

---

Javascript:

```
$('.mainlogin').submit(function() {
    var username = $('#main_username').val();
    var password = $('#main_pword').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'log.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            user: username,
            pass: password
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == 'success') {
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                $('.logerror').fadeIn(250);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
require_once('.conf.php');
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accountController WHERE username = '$user'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if (sha1($user.$pass) == $row['pword']) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['uname'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            echo "success";
        } 
    }    
?>
```

Comment: What does "won't work" mean?  What exactly happens?  What response do you get back from the ajax call?  Are you getting an error?  Have you looked at the network traffic in the Chrome or Firebug debuggers to see exactly what is being sent and returned on the ajax call?  Does the success handler get called?  Have you tried adding an error: handler to see if that gets called and what it gets sent?  This is all standard debugging techniques for ajax calls that aren't working properly.

Comment: So, well, nothing. Nothing happens. I have checked debug panel and it isn't sending anything. It isn't sending the username or password. It isn't even connecting to log.php. I get absolutely no response from the ajax call because nothing is being sent.

Comment: On the first load of your project did you saw a pop-up? Something like "Allow blocked content", if so, did you accept it? If not, try to enable it by going tools. Or the quickest way is to clear your cache and try to reload the page and make sure you allow blocked contents.

Comment: @DanKanze is it IE5.5? That would be fun...

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but you can try adding `cache: false` as an ajax option.  I know this effects IE/Ajax on get calls, but I wouldn't have thought it would make a difference on posts, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @DanKanze It is IE8, IE9 works around 25% of the time. Even more annoying than not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### @"IE8, IE9 works around 25% of the time."

Becuase IE8:

"uses the first session cookie set and not the last as in Firefox."
http://anvilstudios.co.za/blog/php/session-cookies-faulty-in-ie8/

To fix this problem all you need to do is set:

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Which deletes old session id and forces IE8 to use the new one.

### @FAIL:

Caching may be the problem, try adding:

```
cache: false,
```

### @FAIL2:

```
success: function(response) {
            if (response == 'success') {

                 document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=http.responseText;
            }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Even if I purposely type in bogus usernames and passwords, it doesn't show the error. I think this is more a javascript error than php because it simply isn't sending anything. Nice try though!

Comment: did you put that after session_start() ?

Comment: Tried adding `cache: false,` first and it still didn't work. I just noticed that the page reloads when the form is submitted no matter what. I just realized this, never saw it before. How do I prevent it from reloading on form submit?

Comment: im going to go out on a limb and say mabye its becuase you are using window.location.reload();  ?

Comment: How would I reload the page without using that? The only way for me to actually load the content of my site behind the log in is through a refresh?

Comment: see theres your problem right there. you want to reload elements on your page, not the entire page. you want to return a response through singled out elements. thats the entire point of ajax. take the above edit for example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8727/discussion-between-joseph-torraca-and-dan-kanze)